# what would i need in order to build a price look up service or a price comparison service?

Tags: javascript, php, search, lookup

What id need it to do is login in to another websites account and look up prices for items as it applies to that user. this is because the users may have specific contract deals that gives them cheaper prices. id then need to show all of the results side by side and maybe link to the company offereing the price but it wouldn't have to do anymore than that (like buying etc). I am familiar with HTML, CSS and PHP, but please tell me if i need to learn another language, frameworks i can start with etc. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check with "another website" about availability of API for finding the information you need.

Generally, if API is available - you will be able to get the profile or account info, to find out a group of the user (if the discounts are provided to the groups, like "beginner" get 5%, "advanced" get 10% rates), or activity (make 500 posts on the forum - get 10%, buy 10000$ worth of products within a year - get 15% discount) and etc. After that you might get another API function to use which will give you the product info and price actual for the user.

If API is not available, you will need to find out what is available.

Worst way in terms of work required for programming and etc - you have to use pure PHP or perhaps some browser imitating library to manually authorize with your users's login and password, store session and browse the "another website". But a question here - will your users provide you with their login and password for "another website"??

At this point it isn't a PHP, Javascript or anything else question. It is a question of how you can get your data.

Comment: thanks a lot, yes the user would provide the user and password.

Comment: just check the "another website" then. what they have in terms of API and etc.